# How to fetch custom post by Author?

Tags: custom-post-types, author

Here is code , basically I want to fetch by Post author but not able to solve this any help regards this .

```
<?php 
 global $post;
                  $author = get_the_author();
                    $args = array(
                        'author'  =>$user_ID,
                        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
                         'author'=> $author,
                        'post_type' => 'ultimate-auction',
                        //'auction-status' => 'expired',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'offset' => $pagination,
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_key' => 'wdm_listing_ends',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        );  
    $author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $author_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while( $author_posts->have_posts()) {
            $author_posts->the_post();
            ?>
            <?php the_content();?></div>
    <?php
            // you should have access to any of the tags you normally
            // can use in The Loop
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'author' => ...` twice in your code.

To get the author's ID, you should use `get_the_author_meta('ID')` instead. So, remove the second author argument, and use this in your code:

```
  $author = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
        'author'=> $author,
        'post_type' => 'ultimate-auction',
        //'auction-status' => 'expired',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'offset' => $pagination,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'wdm_listing_ends',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
```

By the way, the global `$post` itself contains the ID of post's author, which you can get it by using `$post->post_author;`.

If you want to use the author's name, you can use `'author_name' => ...` together with `get_the_author_meta('nicename')`.

Take a look at [author parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) of `WP_Query` in the WordPress codex for more details.

Comment: this is not working , all user have all post , this is not sorting at by author user id

Comment: Although I didn't quite understand what you mean, but where do you use this code? This is important.

Comment: I ask question with code

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $current_user->ID,
    'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
    'order'         =>  'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
```

Comment: You should add helpful content, hints to understand the source code.

Comment: Code only answers are not an acceptable. You need to explain how the given code solves the issue and where it's added.